# Internet via openVPN

Tags: server, internet, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I managed it to install openVPN on a virtual host and the connection works great, but I am not able to use the internet through the openvpn server (it s only possible to ping the servers ip).

How can I configure the OpenVPN server to access the internet? I enabled ip-forwarding, but I don't know how the

```
pull "route xxxxxxxxxx"
```

command exactly works. I should enter the local ip and subnet, but how can I get it? I only know the server's static IP.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to run a proxy on the server which is providing the openvpn connection.
E.g.:
Your openvpn network is on the 10.0.0.x subnet and your openvpn server does have the ip 10.0.0.1. Then you could run a tinyproxy instance listening on 10.0.0.1:8080.
Then you openvpn client just have to set the proxy (in Firefox, IE, ...) to 10.0.0.1:8080.